# Can you set the colour for contacts in Android 5 Lollipop?

Tags: contacts, 5.0-lollipop, people-app, color

I just upgraded to Android 5.0 which made all my contacts' random colours even more prominent.

Is it possible to customize the colour for each contact? For example, if I don't like that Mister Brown got a green background, can I change that, haha?

Comment: Well, I don't know quite well about it but I ran down a little googling over it and according to  a post over reddit "icons change color depending upon the picture" So I would say try changing the picture and see if the color changes or not I can't confirm this as still I am not running Lollipop over any of my device.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. The problem is most contacts have no picture. I don't really want to add pictures to all of them, so changing just the colour would be awesome.

Comment: Well at this point I can't add up more over here. I'll try a little more googling and will let you know about it, if I came up with something that would help you !

Comment: Thanks again. I Google'd this myself before posting. I think Android 5 is still too new.

Answer (score 5):

Go to google messenger app. (The new SMS app from Google) -> go into a conversation with the contact you want to change colors -> press the three dots on top -> pick People & options -> around the end you'll see a small color palette where you can go in and change the color.

It seems that it currently works ONLY for people you texted (only through the messenger app).

Comment: Yeah, I know about that but it doesn't (yet?) propagate to the Contacts app.

Comment: Cool! I'm using messenger now.

Comment: Yep, this only changes colours in the [Google Messenger App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en), which I don't even use, and had to install. It doesn't change colour in the Contact app, nor the (Cyanogenmod) stock messaging app.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find a way to change the color of a contact either, but did find an inconvenient workaround. It's really only useful for a few contacts (I just cared about those on speed dial).

Find a contact with the color you do want, then change the name and number. Then make a new contact for the one whose information you deleted (or switch them). The color will stay the same.

So if I want Mr. Green to be green even though his contact color is blue, I can go find a green contact (say, Bob), change the name, number, and anything else to fit Mr. Green, then make a new entry for Bob.

Mr. Brown is out of luck though, since there is no brown.

Comment: Haha, yeah, but that'll take ages. Still, good workaround.